# How do scrapy crawlspider rules work?

Tags: scrapy

I have an issue with crawlspider rules.

here my rule definition;

```
rules = (

    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=("/liste/.*/department\.aspx\?categoryId=\d+", ))),

    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=("/liste/.*/department\.aspx\?categoryId=.*&pn=\d+", ))),

    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/liste/.*/productDetails\.aspx\?productId=.*&categoryId=.*', )), callback='parse_page'),

)
```

What I am supposed to--> at first rule, I want to find categories link, then send request these links and find links according  to second rule and send request these links too from extracted second rule . Finally, I want to find links according to rule 3 definition and call_back parse_page function.

But it does not work like what I am supposed. Actually I can not control spider, every run-time it can scraps different pages not all pages. I want to scrap all pages that matches to rules.

How should define my rules to manage this ?

Comment: What does it mean 'it does not work`? What are you expecting to happen? Are the regex expressions correct, have you tested them manually? What is the site in question so we can have a look?

Comment: yes I tested regex expressions, they are correct.

Comment: What I mean , it does not get all pages that matched with rules. Could you explain how the rules I defined work? Maybe I am thinking wrong.

Comment: This is a duplicate question, there is an explanation about how the rules work here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347279/how-does-scrapy-use-rules/25352434#25352434

Comment: @elias agreed, please vote to close this question. Thanks.