# In which order do the rules get evaluated in the CrawlSpider?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a question regarding the order in which the rules get evaluated in a CrawlSpider. If I have the code below:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.crawl import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    start_urls = ['http://someurlhere.com']
    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=[
                "//ul[@class='menu-categories']",
                "//ul[@class='menu-subcategories']"]),
            callback='first_callback'
        ),
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow='/product.php?id=\d+'),
            callback='second_callback'
        )
    )
```

In this case:

- The engine will send a request for `'http://someurlhere.com'` in the `start_url` list and call the default `parse` callback when it gets the response.
- Then in the parse method, from the response it gets from the above step it will extract the links from that response based of the xpath we provided to the FIRST LinkExtractor.

Now my question is the links that are extracted from the FIRST `LinkExtractor` rule, are they simply scheduled in the scheduler and not followed immediately? So after it schedules all the links which are extracted from the first `LinkExtractor` then it will call the `first_callback` method for all of those links with the response passed to that `first_callback`?

Also when is the second `LinkExtractor` going to be called? Does the first `LinkExtractor` get evaluated and then only the second `LinkExtractor` runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we go through the [official documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules). The process is simple.

First, your start url is parsed and then every subsequent crawled pages links will be extracted by the rules provided.

Now coming to your question.

> Now my question is the links that are extracted from the FIRST
>   LinkExtractor rule, are they simply scheduled in the scheduler and not
>   followed immediately? So after it schedules all the links which are
>   extracted from the first LinkExtractor then it will call the
>   first_callback method for all of those links with the response passed
>   to that first_callback?

If callback is `None` follow defaults to `True`, otherwise it defaults to `False`. It means in your case, there will be no follow-up. Whatever link it has extracted from the start URL response is what you will have in scheduler and your crawling will end after parsing all these.

If you want to follow, break the rules. Find where is your content and where are the resourses.

```
# Extract links matching 'products' (but not matching 'shampoo')
# and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('products', ), deny=('shampoo', ))),

# Extract links matching 'item' and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('item', )), callback='parse_item'),
```

Now coming to your second question:

> Also when is the second LinkExtractor going to be called? Does the
>   first LinkExtractor get evaluated and then only the second
>   LinkExtractor runs?

One is not dependent on other. `LinkExtractor` Object apply regex or string matching independently. If they find their matching URL, they proceed with their callbacks or follow up.

Comment: So essentially in my case after getting the `'http://someurlhere.com'` response, all the links which match both of the `LinkExtractors` xpaths will be extracted from that response and put into the scheduler. Then the correct callbacks for each of those extracted links after the scheduler passes those extracted links to the Downloader which gets the responses and passes it back to the engine and finally to the spider to continue?

Comment: Yes, the correct extracted link will call the callback method which parses the data and spider will continue till it get exhausted with the links.

Comment: One more quick question. If I specify the first `LinkExtractor` follow parameter to `True`, then when we get back the response from `'http://someurlhere.com'`, when it matches the links from that response against the first `LinkExtractor` it will immediately follow into that extracted link correct? Then how does it get the links that it should extract from the second `LinkExtractor`?

Comment: See, the `follow=True` means, If I got the link, I will move on to this link and again add the extracted link to the scheduler. For the second, `LinkExtractor` it would just function as it was during `start_url`. Considered these rules are `OR` types, so if the link pattern matches for second `LinkExtractor` it will do its job i.e. call the callback function in your case.

Comment: Sorry for asking another question but I want to clarify something again. `"For the second, LinkExtractor it would just function as it was during start_url."` That I get since there is no `follow=true`. But I still have trouble understanding the `follow=true` LinkExtractor. You stated: `"The follow=True means, If I got the link, I will move on to this link and again add the extracted link to the scheduler"`. So when you say `I will move on to this link` will it actually go into that link and run both of the LinkExtractor again (the first one with follow and the second without follow)?

Comment: As I explained, if `LinkExtractor` found a link which falls into `follow=True` rule, say (`http://example.com/archives`), then it means it will not call the `callback` function and parse the content rather it will extract all the link available in `http://example.com/archives`  and add all these links to scheduler. Now when scheduler revisits these extracted links and again it will do the same thing.