# How to scrape information about a specific product using search bar

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm making a system - mostly in **Python with Scrapy** - in which I can, basically, find information about a **specific product**. But the thing is that the request URL is massive huge, I got a clue that I should change some parts of it with variables to reach that specific product in which I would like to search for, but the URL has so many fields that I don't know, for sure, how to make it.

**e.g**: "https://www.amazon.com.br/s?k=demi+lovato+365+dias+do+ano&adgrpid=86887777368&hvadid=392971063429&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9047761&hvnetw=g&hvpos=1t1&hvqmt=e&hvrand=11390662277799676774&hvtargid=kwd-597187395757&hydadcr=5658_10696978&tag=hydrbrgk-20&ref=pd_sl_21pelgocuh_e%2Frobot.txt"

"**demi+lovato+365+dias+do+ano**" it's the book title, but I can see a lot of information on URL that I simply can't supply and of course, it changes from title to title. One solution I thought could be possible was to POST on search bar the title in which I was looking for and find it on result page but I don't know if it's the best approach since in fact, this is the first time I'll be working with web scraping.

Someone has some tip for how can I do that. All I could find was how to *scrape* all products for price comparison, scrape specific information about all these products and things like that but nothing about search for **specific products**.

Thanks for any contribs, this is very important for me and sorry about anything, I'm not a very present user and I'm not an English native speaker.

Feel free to make me any advice about user behavior, be better is always something I aim to.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [rule](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule) available in scrapy framework. This will help you to define how to navigate the site and its sub-site. Additionally you can configure other tags like span or div other than anchor tags  to look for url of the link. By this way, additional query params in the link will be populated by the scrapy session as it emulate click on the hypelinks. If you skip the additional query params in the URL, there is a high chance that you will be blocked

[How does scrapy use rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347279/how-does-scrapy-use-rules)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to follow that long link at all, often the different parameters are associated with your current session or settings/filters and you can keep only what you need.

Here is what I meant:

You can generate same result using these 2 urls:

https://www.amazon.com.br/s?k=demi+lovato+365+dias+do+ano

https://www.amazon.com.br/s?k=demi+lovato+365+dias+do+ano&adgrpid=86887777368&hvadid=392971063429&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9047761&hvnetw=g&hvpos=1t1&hvqmt=e&hvrand=11390662277799676774&hvtargid=kwd-597187395757&hydadcr=5658_10696978&tag=hydrbrgk-20&ref=pd_sl_21pelgocuh_e%2Frobot.txt

If both links are generating same results then that's it, otherwise you will definitely have to play with different parameters, you can't predict website behavior without actually doing the test and having a lot of parameters is an issue then try something like:

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

base_url = "https://www.amazon.com.br"
link = base_url + "/k=%s&adgrpid=%s&hvadid=%s" % ( quote_plus(title), '86887777368', '392971063429' )
```