# Scrapy CrawlSpider iterating through entire site

Tags: scrapy

I have a simple CrawlSpider that crawls the first page of a specific website. I want to have the spider go ahead with ?p=1, ?p=2 and so on until it detects the end of site-iteration. How can I do that?

```
class PomosCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'crawlobituaries'
    
    allowed_domains = ['some.at']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.some.at',
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='traueranzeigen'), callback='parse_obi'),
    )

    def parse_obi(self, response):
        logging.info(response.url)

        for post in response.css('.homepage_unterseiten_layout_todesanzeigen'):
            for entry in post.css('a'):
                item = {
                    'name': entry.css('.homepage_unterseiten_layout_titel::text').get(),
                    'date': entry.css('.homepage_unterseiten_layout_datum::text').get()
                }
                yield item
```

Comment: Without the actual url you are scraping it is difficult to help you. However as a suggestion you can add a rule that extracts the links to the next pages and add callbacks as required.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't provide the actual URL. Thank you for your suggestion, I'm tryin to figure it out with navigation like this:
`https://<domain>/<sub>--5683197-de.html
https://<domain>/<sub>--5683197-de.html?p=2
https://<domain>/<sub>--5683197-de.html?p=3`

Comment: I really don't know how to define a rule that will scrapy command to ?p=2, ?p=3, and so on, nor if that is possible at all?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347279/how-does-scrapy-use-rules)

Comment: Thanks a lot - I've added a second rule
`Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'p=\d+'), callback='parse_obi'),`
but it doesn't crawl into the second or later pages; in my opinion the regex should be fine?

Comment: Are the next pages on the initial page scraped?

Comment: No, only the initial page itself is being scraped. After that, the spider closes: `INFO: Closing spider (finished)`

Comment: Well I guess you’ll have to figure it out on your own now. Without the url I can’t help you any further

Comment: I've updated the URL in the initial code...

Comment: See the answer. Consider accepting it if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your spider is only scraping the first page is because you have not added `follow=True` in your `Rule` definition so that the spider follows the links and extracts further links. You also need to add a `Rule` definition to follow the next pages which can be defined using `restrict_css` method and include the class on the navigation div. See below sample code.

```py
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import logging

class PomosCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'crawlobituaries'

    allowed_domains = ['bestattung-aichinger.at']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.bestattung-aichinger.at',
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_text='Traueranzeigen'), callback='parse_obi', follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css=".seitenzahlen"), callback='parse_obi', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_obi(self, response):
        logging.info(response.url)

        for post in response.css('.homepage_unterseiten_layout_todesanzeigen'):
            for entry in post.css('a'):
                item = {
                    'name': entry.css('.homepage_unterseiten_layout_titel::text').get(),
                    'date': entry.css('.homepage_unterseiten_layout_datum::text').get()
                }
                yield item
```